# How can I disable a unique constraint whose name is lowercase?

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have the following constraint (queried from `user_constraints`):

[image]

However, whenever I run

```
ALTER TABLE fnn_fin_inst DISABLE CONSTRAINT short_code_unique;
```

I get the following error:

[image]

There are similar constraints that I can disable and enable with no problems. The only difference I can see with this one is that its name is in lowercase. However, Oracle seems to automatically convert the given constraint name to uppercase so I can't get it to attempt to disable the correct constraint. I also can't change the constraint's name for the same reason.

Comment: put the lower-case constraint name in double-quotes. This applies to all case-sensitive names (not only constraints, but also tables, columns, indexes, etc.)

Comment: @mathguy Cheers. That worked. I only tried single quotes. If you'd like, add an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle SQL is generally case-insensitive. Identifiers (names of tables, columns, indexes, views, etc. - including constraints) are saved in the catalog tables in upper-case. When we use identifiers in our queries, they are first converted to upper-case.

**UNLESS**

we use double-quotes. First when we create the names: if we want them to be case sensitive, we use double-quotes in the `create ...` statement, like so:

```
create table ...
( ... columns ...
  constraint "my_constraint" check (... something ...)
);
```

Notice the constraint name in double-quotes.

Then whenever we reference that name, it must appear in double-quotes in our statements.

Not like this:

```
  ... disable constraint my_constraint
```

but like this:

```
  ... disable constraint "my_constraint"
```